# Try to CSS a JQUery ui-tabs

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML codes

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/tshirt.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Shirt Builder</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Add QR Message</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">View Product</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Checkout</a></li>

  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
     <img src="img/tabs.png" width="300" height="200" align="left">
    <p>P1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>P2.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">

    <p>P3.</p>
  </div>

   <div id="tabs-4">

    <p>Page 4.</p>
  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

When I inspect the element

```
div#tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all 1106px x 282px
```

so, In my css style sheet, I have

```
#tabs
{
width:400px;

}
```

but I cannot change the width of ui-tabs, it still remains at 1106px.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the actual css.

Try using this:

```
.ui-tabs{
  width:400px;
}
```

You have to apply this class in your page.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ukcaz/)

Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

**class to style all tabs**

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li{width:50px}
```

**class for only style the active tab**

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a{width:50px}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#tabs
{
width:400px !important;

}
```

Comment: -1: `!important` should never be the go-to solution for anything you need to override in CSS.

Comment: this is done to apply our css without the use of  js i am giving this answer according to the user problem always dislike is not a solution you can give advise ... any way thanks brother